# send ejabberd push notification ( django )

Tags: python, ios, django, push-notification, ejabberd

I have integrated ejabberd for chat functionality. Apps backend is in python-django and frontend is in IOS. current flow is as follows :

1. When user signup into my app, A record has been created for that user in ejabberd server. This thing is handled in backend. unique id for that user is the combination of primary key and name ( e.g - 123_mark@xyz.com )
2. To chat on frontend , IOS is using these id's. When both users are online , they can chat successfully.

Problem -   When a user gets offline or a user kills the application, Then   backend has to send notifications to device. I have checked ejjaberd's documentation. According to them I have to use mod_zeropush to send notifications. I have checked some articles, but I am not sure how to send notification to users. Can someone explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see ZeroPush mod leverages a ZeroPush server, I might be wrong about this as I just glanced through their pages.

What you need to do is to create your own mod which hooks into events that are occurring in ejabberd. This Q&A sums it up: [How to develop custom functions on top of Ejabberd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193106/how-to-develop-custom-functions-on-top-of-ejabberd/22196423#22196423)

Basically you need to find out which event is fired when a user disconnects and hook into that event so your mod would be executed.